# What is best algorithm for semiprime factoring?

Tags: prime-factoring

What is best algorithm for semiprime factoring? It can be different from multiprime factoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You factor a semiprime the same way you factor any composite. Use trial division and pollard rho to get the low-hanging fruit, if there is any. Then p-1, p+1 and elliptic curves until you are convinced that the factors are too large. Finish with either quadratic sieve or number field sieve.